# Adding Approvers in a Sequential Workflow Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-activity

I have a sequential workflow which is associated to a listwhich contains column name Business Process which could be Purchase Order, Sales, Leave Request etc

I have another list 'Approvers' which contains two columns Group Name & Approvers

eg: Purchase Order                Approver1, Approver2

```
  Sales                                 Approver1, Approver2, Approver3
```

I have created the workflow for the list, but I am not getting an idea as to how to get and loop through the approvers based on the list value.

The following is my code

```
namespace wfmaintenance.Workflow1
```

{
    public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
    {
        public Workflow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    public string Company;
    public string BusinessProcess;
    public string ListName;
    public string WorkflowName;
    public string WorkflowInitiation;




    public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
    public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

    public SPWorkflowTaskProperties WfTaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
    public SPWorkflowTaskProperties WfTaskBeforeProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
    public Guid WfApproveTaskId = default(Guid);
    public int WfApproveTaskItemId;
    public bool WfApproveComplete = false;

    private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        /**  Company = workflowProperties.Item["Company"].ToString();
          BusinessProcess = workflowProperties.Item["BusinessProcess"].ToString();
          ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
          WorkflowName = workflowProperties.Item["WorkflowName"].ToString();
          WorkflowInitiation = workflowProperties.Item[" WorkflowInitiation"].ToString();
          checkApprovalStatus();
```

**/
        }

```
    private void notWfTaskApproved(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = !WfApproveComplete;
    }



    private void createWfTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;

        // Set up some of the properties.
        WfApproveTaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
        WfTaskProperties.Title = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString() + " is ready for review";
        WfTaskProperties.Description = "Please review and ensure it is valid.  If it is valid, then please select 'Approved' on this task and save it.";

    }

    private void onWfTaskChanged_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        //int tid = onWfTaskChanged.AfterProperties.TaskItemId;
        SPListItem task = workflowProperties.Web.Lists["Workflow Tasks"] .GetItemById(WfApproveTaskItemId);

        SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;

try
{

    if (task["Business Approval"] != null)
    {
        // Evaluate the value of the field.
            if (task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Approved" || task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Rejected")

                {
                    WfApproveComplete = true;
                    task[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
                    task["Status"] = "Completed";
                    task.Update();



                }
                else
                {
                    WfApproveComplete = false;

                }
    }
    else
    {

        WfApproveComplete = false;

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    WfApproveComplete = false;

}
```

}

```
    private void completeWfTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 SPListItem task = workflowProperties.Web.Lists["Workflow Tasks"] .GetItemById(WfApproveTaskItemId);

//task[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
//task["Status"] = "Completed";
//task.SystemUpdate(false);


SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;
if (task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Rejected")
{
    string ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
    string currentTitle = workflowProperties.Item["Status"].ToString();
    workflowProperties.Item["Status"] = ListName + "is Rejected ";
    workflowProperties.Item.Update();
}
else
{
    string ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
    string currentTitle = workflowProperties.Item["Status"].ToString();
    workflowProperties.Item["Status"] =  "is Approved ";
    workflowProperties.Item.Update();
}
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One issue I'm seeing here is that the 'Assigned To' field on workflow tasks only accepts one SPUser or one SPGroup, but not multiples (at least not by default). If you need multiple approvers for a single task, I would suggest refactoring a bit to use SharePoint groups instead of a list of individual users for task approver assignments.

In your `createWfTask_MethodInvoking` method, you'll want to look up your 'Approvers' list based on the 'Business Process' for this workflow instance's SPListItem (`workflowProperties.Item`). You could achieve this with a SPQuery (caml) or LINQ. If you modified your 'Approvers' list to contain either a single user or a group in the 'Approvers' column, you could then grab that value.

Once you have your group or user you wish to assign the task to, you want to set the '[AssignedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtaskproperties.assignedto%28v=office.14%29.aspx)' property of your `WfTaskProperties` object to be either the user's `LoginName` or the group's name.

Comment: I am a newbie to visual studio, is it possible for you to just code that part as to how to achieve it. Thanks

Comment: I have modified my APprovers list and made it with one user for eg        Group name : Purchase Order Approver : User 1 and second field Group name: Purchase Order Approver : User 2